# Angular : Get `404` after reload with `GitHub` page

Tags: angular, github-pages

I have deployed my `Angular` website on `GitHub` page, but I got a problem.

The below is my `route` setting:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'main', component: AppMainComponent }
];
```

The below is my deployment commands:

```sh
- name: Build
        run: |
          npm install -g @angular/cli
          npm install
          ng build --prod --base-href=https://[user-name].github.io/[project-name]/
        
- name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v2
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          BASE_BRANCH: master
          BRANCH: gh-pages
          FOLDER: dist/[project-name]
```

If I go to my `GitHub` page, "https://[user-name].github.io/[project-name]/", it worked fine and redirected to "https://[user-name].github.io/[project-name]/main" successfully. But after I clicked reload button of the browser, it showed `404 page not found` to me.

My Angular version is 9.1.8.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Angular [doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages), you have to make a copy of `index.html` and name it `404.html`.

> 3. When the build is complete, make a copy of docs/index.html and name it docs/404.html.
>
> `bash ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href/<project_name>/`

Comment: correct `ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href project_name`